# rewriting image urls to other domain does not work (gives 404)

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Something is wrong with the following rewrite rule. I thought I was doing it the right way since i copied from a book other than it's supposed to redirect to another domain.

I got the following url:

`http://www.domaina.com/some-Text-is-here-B40178.jpg`

the image is located at the url:

`http://www.domainb.com/imgs/B40178.jpg`

How should the underneath rewrite rule be written in order to make this work?

`RewriteRule ^.*-B([0-9]+)\../$ http://www.domainb.com/imgs/B$1 [L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is missing the extension so it's not matching. Also it looks like you have an extra / on the end. If it's always jpg you could add that. Or just match anything at the end.

Also you need to capture that extension as well.

Matches "jpg"

```
RewriteRule ^.*-B([0-9]+\.jpg)$ http://www.domainb.com/imgs/B$1 [R,L]
```

Matches anything

```
RewriteRule ^.*-B([0-9]+\..+)$ http://www.domainb.com/imgs/B$1 [R,L]
```

My preferred method, match certain image types:

```
RewriteRule ^.*-B([0-9]+)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ http://www.domainb.com/imgs/B$1.$2 [R,L]
```

**EDIT** Missed that you were redirecting to another domain. You need the R flag as well. I've added it.

Comment: With the addition to gif I like your preferred solution as well haha Yeah it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the rule as a Redirect, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^.*-B([0-9]+)\../$ http://www.domainb.com/imgs/B$1 [R,L]
```

EDIT: you also need to tack on the file extension. I'm going to be lazy and assume they're all JPGs:

```
RewriteRule ^.*-B([0-9]+).jpg$ http://www.domainb.com/imgs/B$1.jpg [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks but it still gives a 404 so i guess there's more wrong with it

Comment: Oh, it looks like you're not passing/matching the file extension.

Comment: Yes that was the issue, the above solution fixed it. I already thought it a bit weird how the extension could be passed like that but then i thought no the book can't be wrong. How wrong i was...

Comment: btw, the extension can be anything hahaha But doesn't .jpg needs to be \.jpg ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found a better solution that doesn't use a redirect:

```
 RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^$
 RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/
 RewriteRule  .*              -    [R=400,L]
 RewriteRule ^.*-B([0-9]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|JPG|GIF|PNG|JPEG)$ http://www.domain.com/imgs/B$1.$2 [P,L]`
```

So in the URL it won't look like the image doesn't come from another domain. P stands for Proxy (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html)